# 1M+ concurrent connections and Programming Languages

Tags: sockets, connection

Every time I search for 1M+ concurrent connections to read about it, I see articles of some solutions or study cases in languages like Elixir, Erlang, Go, sometimes node.js, and so on, but never in more "traditional" languages like C/C++, D, Java, or any other "low level" language around.

There is a intrinsic reason for this? Like an inability for these languages of being able to reach high levels of concurrency or there is some other reason for not seeing these type of articles in these languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that prevents "traditional" languages from achieving high levels of concurrency. Using async libraries and suitable data structures you should be able to get similar, or even better results.

If you think about it, most of the compilers/interpreters of that "concurrent" languages are written in C/C++, which should imply that C/C++ is capable of doing large amounts of concurrency.

Comment: "(...)are written in C/C++". Exactly. And that´s the reason I got suspicious about not seeing articles of high concurrency on c/c++.